# Is ZFC a seamless embodiment of the notion of a hierarchy?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Add one place function $V$ to the language of set theory.

Add axioms of: **Extensionality; Separation**, stipulated in the usual manner.

*Define* $``ordinal"$ along Von Neumann's.

**Stages:** $\forall \ ordinal \ \alpha: V_\alpha = \{x \subseteq V_\beta | \beta < \alpha\}$

**Foundation:** $\forall x \exists \ ordinal \ \alpha \  ( x \in V_\alpha    )$

**Infinity:** $\exists \alpha [\alpha \neq \emptyset \land \forall \beta < \alpha \exists \gamma (\beta < \gamma < \alpha)]$

**Height:** $\forall x \exists \ ordinal \ \alpha: \exists f \ (f: x \rightarrowtail \alpha) $

I personally consider this fragment of **ZFC** which appears to have $V_{\theta}$ [where $\theta$ is the first fixed point $\theta=\omega_\theta$] as its domain; to be the most natural of impredicative set theories, more natural than both **ZC** and **ZFC**

Now we can go beyond that easily to heights passing those of **ZFC**, for example we can add a *single* axiom stipulating that there exists a regular limit of regular cardinals, and this would be the first weakly inaccessible, and the theory would pass beyond **ZFC**.

> Can we *easily* extend the above theory to just **ZFC**, and what I mean by "easy" here is adding a *single* axiom for that sake? In other words a single statement that make ordinals form *only* as long as they are accessible!

IF that cannot be done, then this means (in my own opinion) that **ZFC** is to some extent not a seamless embodiment of the notion of a particular hierarchy?!

Also I'd like to add this question since its directly connected to this subject:

> Can we *easily* extend the above theory to some extension of **ZFC**?

Comment: I disagree with the last paragraph of your post, but I believe the answer to the actual question is no: if I recall correctly, ZFC is not finitely axiomatizable over ZC. I'll try to add an answer later when I get time.

Comment: As @Noah said, this is unlikely, since you cannot replace Replacement by a single axiom. The final paragraph is wrong. Replacement, which is what is essentially missing from your theory (Power Set follows from your definition of Foundation+Separation, I suppose). But Replacement is equivalent to Reflection. What good is a hierarchy if it doesn't provide you with an *actual* filtration of the universe, in a way that reflects any finite part of its theory on a club? Hierarchies are not good if you don't have tools to use them. Reflection is an incredible **internal** tool for that matter.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Asaf Karagila. If this is so, then this (to me) proves that replacement is something extra to just capturing the notion of a concrete hierarchy, the above theory captures that nicely, and yet its much weaker than **ZFC**. Replacement can be seen (in my view) as capturing the *abstract* notion of a hierarchy, yes; but that is not a nice aspect, its the particularity of a hierarchy that makes it nice to ingrain abstract mathematical notions in it. Having reflections is another matter, you can even have them without having a hierarchy.

Comment: @Zuhair " Replacement can be seen (in my view) as capturing the abstract notion of a hierarchy, yes; but that is not a nice aspect, its the particularity of a hierarchy that makes it nice to ingrain abstract mathematical notions in it." To be honest I don't agree with this at all - to me if anything (I'm not sure I grant the distinction in the first place entirely) it's the other way around. The overarching abstract idea is much more satisfying than the more limited specific object. But this is getting away from the specific technical question of your post.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I prefer to understand ZFC as a longitudinal hierarchical phenomena at certain heights of the hierarchy and those heights are the inaccessible ones, rather than figuring ZFC horizontally in a noise of parallel hierarchies each defined after a different function. In that way ZFC is subsumed into the hierarchy theory but NOT the opposite, i.e. ZFC is nothing but a special case of the Hierarchy theory. The hierarchy theory is the more general and basic notion about sets!

Comment: @AsafKaragila, about *reflection*, this is a *technique* that can be intuitively thought of as a move from above downwards, rather than stepping up from below notion of a hierarchy. I know that with sufficiently high hierarchies it would be implemented, but those are not finitely axiomatizable over this theory!!! which *correctly* shows that it not a seamless embodiment of the notion of a hierarchy. Actually the equivalence of replacement with it even further proves my point! Replacement & reflection are to be seen as *manipulations* of the hierarchy notion, but not genially stemming form it.